# Python regex if all whole words in string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following a string, I need to check if

- the string contains App2 **and** iPhone,
- but not App **and** iPhone

I wrote the following:

```
campaign_keywords = "App2 iPhone"
my_string = "[Love]App2 iPhone Argentina"
pattern = re.compile("r'\b" + campaign_keywords + "\b")
print pattern.search(my_string)
```

It prints None. Why?

Comment: Is that `"r'...` an attempt at denoting a raw string literal, with the `r` as part of the string?...

Comment: the above code gives me `AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'matches'`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 no - r is not part of the string. it's what I saw in examples as the way to write regex in python

Comment: `r` should be outside of the string, try this `r"\b%s\b" % (campaign_keywords)`

Comment: Ah, i missread. ;)

Comment: why vote down? it's a legit question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The raw string notation is wrong, the `r` should not be inside the the quotes. and the second `\b` should also be a raw string.
2. The `match` function tries to match at the start of the string. You need to use `search` or `findall`

   [Difference between `re.search` and `re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

---

**Example**

```
 >>> pattern = re.compile(r"\b" + campaign_keywords + r"\b")

 >>> pattern.findall(my_string)
 ['App2 iPhone']

 >>> pattern.match(my_string)

 >>> pattern.search(my_string)
 <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10ca2fbf8>
 >>> match = pattern.search(my_string)
 >>> match.group()
 'App2 iPhone'
```

Comment: yes. that was my mistake. I didn't see from other questions how to use it with variable. Will fix it soon

Comment: @Dejell I hope it is working with the `search` or `findall`.

Comment: yes it does! thank you!